# Building list with distinct elements that total defined sum

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, c#-4.0

I am looking to build a list with distinct elements that total a defined sum. For example, given the following list with a sum of 61. How would I build a new list to have the same sum of 61, but with distinct elements as opposed to having duplicate values 4, 7, and 9?

```
List<int> ElementList = new List<int> { 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9}

static void BuildDistinctList(List<int> InputList)
{
    InputList.Sort();

    Dictionary<int, int> DistinctValues = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < InputList.Count; i++)
    {
        if(!DistinctValues.ContainsValue(InputList[i]))
        {
            DistinctValues.Add(i, InputList[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            //My thinking at this point would be to no longer mess with
            //the value stored inside of the dictionary as it is fixed from this point 
            //forward, and to borrow from the remaining list values.  

            FindNewDistinctValue(MIN, MAX, DistinctValues, InputList, i, InputList.Count - i); 
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone share some insight as to if I am following an appropriate direction by going this route. Or provide some tips on how to solve this.

Edit: I created the function below, and added it to the else statement in the original code provided. It seems to kind of be working but I appear to be borrowing too much from the values toward the end of the list, and am short on the total sum. This paints a better picture as to what I am looking to do. If you need me to clarify anything feel free to ask.

```
static void FindNewDistinctValue(int Min, int Max, Dictionary<int, int> DistinctValues, List<int> InputList, int CurrentIndex, int BorrowIndex)
{
    for (int i = Min + 1; i < Max; i++)
    {
        if (!DistinctValues.ContainsValue(i))
        {
            int ValueToSubtractFromBorrowIndex = InputList[CurrentIndex] - i;
            DistinctValues.Add(CurrentIndex, i);

            InputList[BorrowIndex] = InputList[BorrowIndex] - ValueToSubtractFromBorrowIndex;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your desired list ?

Comment: Unless you have a constraint on the length of the list, powers of 2 is one standard way to generate any sum with distinct elements. For example: `5 = 1 + 4`, `10 = 2 + 8` and `61 = 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 1`! This may not be what you require, but may be useful.

Comment: @crazyGamer There are constraints on the list. So in the example provided, I would need 10 distinct elements to sum up to 61. I am producing 8 random numbers between 0 and 61, and then creating partitions between the random values to find the sum of the range. At that point, I am attempting to find the distinct values to still equal the given sum. Let me know if you need me to further clarify.

Comment: @M.Rezaeyan Working on creating a sample list with the sample provided.

Comment: If the list needs to have 10 numbers, then the sum needs to be at least 55 (if 0 and negative numbers are not allowed): 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+16=61

Comment: It seems to me a [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) ;).

Comment: Consider using `HashSet` instead of `List` for `ElementList` so you don't need to worry about duplicates.

Comment: @shA.t Quick question regarding the subset sum problem. Wouldn't that result in possibly having duplicate elements in the final result?

Comment: @Slai I can see me adopting this approach, thanks for your insight.